# Compress multiple files and keep their name?

Tags: zip, compression, gzip

I have hundreds of .csv files that I need to compress into one file each. It should look like this

```
originalname.csv.gz
```

Comment: `for f in *.csv; do gzip "$f"; done`

Answer (score 5):

```
$> ls -la *csv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user at 0 Jun 23 15:22 1.csv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user at 0 Jun 23 15:22 2.csv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user at 0 Jun 23 15:22 3.csv
$> gzip *csv
$> ls -la *csv*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user at 26 Jun 23 15:22 1.csv.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user at 26 Jun 23 15:22 2.csv.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user at 26 Jun 23 15:22 3.csv.gz
$>
```